# OpenCL 2D workgroup dimensions

Tags: arrays, graphics, matrix, parallel-processing, opencl

I am having problems in understanding OpenCL 2D workgroup dimensions.

I want to create a N x N matrix and give each row to a set of workgroups for computation.
For example if I have a 1000 x 1000 matrix I would like to have 10 workgroups per row (so each workgroup would compute 100 elements) and 10000 workgroups in total (10 * 1000).

This is a piece of my code:

```
size_t global_pattern[] = {n,n,0}; //My matrix pattern
size_t group_pattern[] = {workgroups_per_row, n, 0}; //My workgroups pattern
```

And some lines below:

```
err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 2, NULL, global_pattern, 
                             group_pattern, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Which fails. The err code is -54 that refers to #define CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE -54.

Is my initialization of the group_pattern array correct? I mean, does the first element of the array refers to the x coordinate and the second one to the y coordinate as I am assuming?
What is the math behind?

For debugging purposes I also tried to run it with an empty kernel (just to be sure that it is not my code the problem). I also tried to swap the first and the second element in the group_pattern array.

Comment: "Which fails". So, what "fails"? Does it crash, SEG_FAULTS, gives an error, in that case which one?

Comment: err != CL_SUCCESS, which is the expected value. If I try to launch it as an 1 dimensional problem it works. I am not sure that with my code I implemented the intended semantic that I described with my question. Is there a way to have more specific error messages? The err value is -54, if it can help.

Comment: If the error is not a success, then is an error yes, but there are 64 types of error codes...

Comment: Thank you. It is -54. I checked online and it is this #define CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE -54 As I was expecting I am doing something wrong with the group size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say:

```
size_t global_pattern[] = {n,n,0}; //My matrix pattern
size_t group_pattern[] = {workgroups_per_row, n, 0}; //My workgroups pattern
```

And then use it like:

```
err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 2, NULL, global_pattern, group_pattern, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

It is clearly wrong. What you have to pass to the kernel is the `local_size` AKA, the size of one group. Not how do you want to split your space.

So it would be like this for your case:

```
size_t global_size[] = {n,n}; //My matrix pattern
size_t group_pattern[] = {workgroups_per_row, n}; //My workgroups pattern
size_t local_size[] = {global_size[0]/group_pattern[0], global_size[1]/group_pattern[1]}; //My workgroups pattern

err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 2, NULL, global_pattern, local_size, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

EDIT: If you have a CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE, then the causes could be that:

1. You are specifying a local size that is not an integer divisor of the global size
2. The device does not support a local size as big as you defined

Comment: I updated with the probably causes of CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE (-54)

Comment: It worked. Thank you. I just got wrong the semantic of the sixth parameter.